# Replace a usercontrol by another one in WPF MaterialDesigntoolkit

Tags: wpf

I would like to be able to click on a `Button` named "More" then I will change the current `UserControl` with another detailed one in the `MainWindow`.

I tried to make the following but the items in leftmenubar don't work anymore when I run the last line of the code below:

```
private void btnMore_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CarDetailsViewModel c = new CarDetailsViewModel();
    (this.Parent as ContentControl).Content = new CarDetails { DataContext = c };
}
```

I am using http://materialdesigninxaml.net/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be like so:

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:CarDetails />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

Code behind:

```
private void btnMore_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CarDetailsViewModel c = new CarDetailsViewModel();
    (this.Parent as ContentControl).Content = c;
}
```

Ideally, the car details viewmodel should be a property of a parent viewmodel bound to the content control's Content:

```
<ContentControl
    Content="{Binding SelectedCarDetails}"
    >
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:CarDetails />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

`SelectedCarDetails` would be updated by the parent viewmodel, and/or by selection in a ListBox or ListView, or whatever.

If you want to replace with a usercontrol of a different type, consider using *implicit* data templates:

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:CarDetailsViewModel}">
            <local:CarDetails />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:BikeDetailsViewModel}">
            <local:BikeDetails />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:BoatDetailsViewModel}">
            <local:BoatDetails />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

Those could be defined in the UserControl's Resources, or in the Resources of any parent/grandparent/etc. element in the same XAML file. If you give it a Content of any of those viewmodel types, it'll automagically use the corresponding datatemplate.